# Why is a Pixmap circle off by 1?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to draw a circle using Pixmap. To make the problem clearer, I'm filling the entire Pixmap area in white, then drawing the circle in a different color. Here is the code that I feel should work.

I'm setting the width/height of the Pixmap to twice the size of the radius of the circle.

Then I'm drawing a circle in the middle of the Pixmap at (radius, radius).

```
public static Texture circle(int radius, Color color) {
  Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(radius * 2, radius * 2, Pixmap.Format.RGBA4444);
  pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  pixmap.fill();
  pixmap.setColor(color);
  pixmap.fillCircle(radius, radius, radius);
  Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);
  pixmap.dispose();
}
```

Unfortunately, the Pixmap cuts off the circle on the right and bottom sides. For example:

[image]

If I increase the size of the Pixmap by 1 in both the width and height, then it looks fine:

[image]

I can just arbitrarily add an extra pixel but I'd like to understand why this is necessary. Why does setting the radius of the circle to X result in a diameter that is actually X + 1?

Comment: What result do you expect for a radius of 0? No circle or a single-dot circle?

Comment: This one pixel probably is the center of the circle. When drawing the width of a circle, you draw the center pixel, `radius` pixels to the left and `radius` pixels to the right, total of `radius * 2 + 1`.

Comment: I'm anxious to know if changing the center of the circle to `(radius-0.5, radius-0.5)` will solve your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch - good question. I would have expected no circle but I actually got a single-dot circle. I guess that answers the question also. Thanks, this is a good way of reasoning.

Comment: @Steve - I think that would solve the issue but unfortunately, fillCircle only takes an int so radius - 0.5 is not possible!

Comment: Ok.  I expect that goes for the radius of the circle as well, and so just adding 1 to the width and height is the best you can do, and more importantly, now you understand why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you want, the location of the circle's center would have to fall between two pixels, so that there are a similar number of whole pixels on either side of that location.  My guess is that the Pixmap code defines a pixel's location to mean the center of a pixel.  So the point `(radius, radius)` is closer to the right edge than the left, and `(radius-1, radius-1)` is closer to the left edge than the right.  With this definition of location, the center of your circle should be at location `(radius-.5, radius-.5)`.

If you have to put the center of the circle in the middle of a pixel, then it makes sense that you'd use the location `(radius, radius)` for the circle and that you'd need the width and height of the Pixmap to be `(2*radius + 1, 2*radius+1)`.  This way, there are the same number of pixels, `radius+.5` pixels, on either side of the center of the circle.  You might at that point want to draw a circle of radius `radius + .5` if the library will take that.

Answer (score 1):

Because it draws a circle centered **on** a pixel, not *between* pixels.

So the actual radius of the circle drawn is one more than passed in, a circle with radius 1 is drawn as (numbers are coordinates in this example):

```
 012
0 X
1XCX
2 X
```

This technically has a radius of 1.5, but now it's centered on a pixel (C).
I am guessing this is to allow you to place it accurately, as if it actually had a radius of 2, you wouldn't be able to place the center on a pixel.

Comment: Yes.  As I try to say in my answer, to get a radius of 2 to work out, you'd want the location of the circle to be (0.5, 0.5).  I don't know, however, if the library will do the right thing with that.